# What is the protocol for generating addresss in Cardano?

Tags: cardano-address

I assume the protocol is similar at a high level to Bitcoin:

1. Generate private key from entropy
2. Use ECDSA to make a public key
3. Do some hashing to generate an address (inc checksums etc.)

What are the specific steps at the lower level, for example if we were to code an address generator outside of a wallet, what functions would we need?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [CIP-19](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip19/) - it describes the structure of addresses in Cardano, and is currently active.

Additionally, you may find skimming through [CIP-3](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip3/) and [CIP-5](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip5/) can complement this, as well as [CIP-1852](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip1852/) useful as a refresher.

Cheers!